# Application with plugins is possible in iOS or not?

Tags: ios, plugins

I just want to know that can i make an application which have some plugins in it, when user install that application then some plugins also get installed? for example I make a plugin which have some smilies and when i open Facebook application all that smilies get available to me in that application and in my application also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still what i studied is that you cannot make any thing for iphone that wants to make change or access OS level. SO this in not possible for iOS. But this is some how possible for JailBreak